# Inserting a list of values into Mysql

Tags: java, jdbc

How do I insert a list of values into a column in a MySQL table.

Here is my project:

```
public void settingAmount(List<String>lst)throws Exception{

    // Accessing driver from jar files 
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     // here we create a variable for the connection called con 
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ozon","root","root");
     // here we create our query 
    Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
    //performing insert operation :)
    lst.toArray(ss);

    for(String ins:ss){
        double d=Double.parseDouble(ins);
        String insert = "INSERT INTO storage_other(total) VALUES ("+ins+");";
        //String insert = "INSERT INTO storage_other(amount) VALUES ("+ls+");";
        // Here we are going to Execute the query
        stmt.executeUpdate(insert);
        System.out.print("Done Seccesfully :)");
    }
}
```

Comment: SQL Injection ahead!!! Try to use prepared statements: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: What's the problem? Aside from the SQL Injection potential problem...

Comment: It might not even be a bug but a feature to make sure all strings are parseble as doubles. Not the cleanest solution but if a RTE is fine then...

Answer (score 8):

What you want to do is use `batches`.  Batches allow you to send a list of statements to be done at the same time.

Here is an example

```
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO storage_other(total) VALUES (?)");
for (String ins:ss){
    ps.setObject(1, d);
    ps.addBatch();
}
ps.executeBatch();
connection.commit();
```

This will be significantly faster than individual inserts on any table with indexes.

Comment: Also, retrieving the connection from a Database Connection Pool instead of creating it manually on every call of this method. Also, `Connection#commit` will truly work if the connection is calling `Connection#setAutoCommit(false)` before sending the operations or if the connection already has this attribute as false. Last but not least, close all the resources before finishing the method execution.

Comment: These are all good suggestions, and the op should take them!  They just weren't part of the question though so I opted to exclude.

Comment: Using a `PreparedStatement` wasn't part of OP's question either and he/she didn't add code to close resources either :).

Comment: thanx very much its helping me very much  , this take all my time , thank you

Comment: If the problem is solved you should accept one of the answers. That lets others know that particular answer helped you solve the issue.

Comment: yeh the problem is solved thanx every one , and its helpfull answer :)
have a nice daya guys :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a method I used in order to insert some data in an Oracle SQL database.

```
     private boolean submit(Connection con, String query){
             try {
                 PreparedStatement preStatement;
                 preStatement = con.prepareStatement(query);
                 preStatement.executeQuery();
                 preStatement.close();
                 return true;
             }catch (Exception e) {
                 System.out.println("Exception cought, updating log.");
                 return false;
             }
         }
```

You can prepare your `insert` statement and call this function to perform the action. Call it using your connection object and the query. It shall return `true` on completion `false` in case something goes wrong. If you want to log any errors, use `e.getMessage()` to get the error message as a String in the exception block.

As mentioned in the comments, try to use the `PreparedStatement` object to avoid SQL Injection attacks and also try to trim any `'` you might have in your data.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd recommend you do it.  A few thoughts:

1. Give the Connection to the object.  That method should do one thing: the INSERT.
2. Should be transactional.
3. Should clean up resources when done.
4. Tell users to provide a List of Doubles if that is what the amounts are.  Don't parse; let clients do that.

Here is complete code:

```
public class Inserter {

    private static final String INSERT_SQL = "INSERT INTO storage_other(total) VALUES(?))";

    private Connection connection;

    public Inserter(Connection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    public int settingAmount(List<Double> amounts)throws SQLException {
        int numAmountsInserted = 0;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        this.connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        try {
            ps = this.connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_SQL);
            for(Double amount : amounts) {
                ps.setDouble(1, amount);
                numAmountsInserted += ps.executeUpdate();
            }
            this.connection.commit();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            DatabaseUtils.rollback(this.connection);
            throw e;
        } finally {
            DatabaseUtils.close(ps);
            this.connection.setAutoCommit(true);
        }
        return numAmountsInserted;
    }
}
```